# How to create a chart which consists of 5 subcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

I'm trying to create a Chart image which consists of five subcharts.(see Picture)

[image: ChartImage]

The X Axis of the Chart should be the same for all 5 subcharts.

How can I realize that with MS Chart Controls?

Currently I'm creating all five Charts, but I have no idea how I can merge the xAxis and how to fit all 5 subcharts into an Image file or Chart.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MsChart` allows multiple `ChartArea`. Each chart area can have multiple `Series`.
As per your screen designs, there will be 5 Chart areas. Each `ChartArea` will have 1 series added to it.

```
var chartArea1 = MyChart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea 1");
:
var chartArea5 = MyChart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea 5");
```

Add Series to charts and assign the chart area

```
MyChart.Series[0].ChartArea = chartArea1.Name;
MyChart.Series[5].ChartArea = chartArea5.Name;
```

Now, to have a common X axis, assign the

```
chartArea1.AlignWithChartArea = chartArea5.Name;
chartArea2.AlignWithChartArea = chartArea5.Name;
```

You can also refer the [link](https://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/align-multiple-chart-areas/) for MSChart.

**Update for Chart Area placement**
Below code is to shows how to position the chart areas within a chart control. Note:- X and Y position are in percentage rather then pixels, twips, etc.

```
chartArea1.Position.Y = 0;
chartArea1.Position.Height = 43;
chartArea1.Position.Width = 100;
chartArea2.Position.Y = chartArea1.Position.Bottom + 1;
chartArea2.Position.Height = chartArea1.Position.Height;
chartArea2.Position.Width = chartArea1.Position.Width;
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But the Problem is, that all 5 Chart are not going to be drawn one below the other. I get 3 Charts, which are below the other and the last 2 will be drawn either on the right sight or over the first two Charts. So that means you can not read the first two Charts, because like I said, there are two Charts overlaying each other. How could I fix this?

Comment: old post but thank you for this, better than microsoft documentation

Answer (score -1):

You can do that:

```
ccc =[1, 2, 3, 4,5]
aaa = [11, 8, 12, 3,6]
bbb = [22,24,21,19,20]
ddd = [1,0,2,0,5]
fff = [32,32,41,35,16]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ccc, 'AAA': aaa,'BBB': bbb, 'DDD': ddd, 'FFF': fff })

f, axarr =plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(14, 7))
df['BBB'].plot(ax=axarr[0])
df['AAA'].plot(ax=axarr[1])
df['FFF'].plot(ax=axarr[2])
df['DDD'].plot(ax=axarr[3])
df['BBB'].plot(ax=axarr[4])
```

[image]